# Ansible: editing a config file as sudo (CoreOS)

Tags: ansible, coreos

I'm an ansible newbie.

I'm using ansible 2.3.0.0

I have the playbook below to bootstrap nodes for a k8s cluster in openstack:

```
- name: bootstrap
  hosts: coreos
  become_user: root
  become_method: su
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - defunctzombie.coreos-bootstrap
  tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: /etc/coreos/update.conf
      state: present
      regexp: '^REBOOT_STRATEGY'
      line: 'REBOOT_STRATEGY=off'
```

I want to turn off auto-reboots on coreos because our openstack installation has a problem with reboots not coming back up properly and having coreos reboot often is causing instance to have to be manually shut down and restarted.

Anyway, the playbook above doesn't work.  I get this error:

```
"The destination directory (/etc/coreos) is not writable by the current user. Error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/coreos/.ansible_tmppQCJrCupdate.conf'"
```

So my syntax is wrong (I've tried a few different combinations with no luck).

Could someone point me in the right direction?  And feel free to make a suggestion on anything about this playbook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of execute playbook as `root` user, use different user with `sudo` access.

Please try this:

```yml
- name: bootstrap
  hosts: coreos
  user: <user_name>
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - defunctzombie.coreos-bootstrap
  tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: /etc/coreos/update.conf
      state: present
      regexp: '^REBOOT_STRATEGY'
      line: 'REBOOT_STRATEGY=off'
```

Replace `<user_name>` with your user.

Run your playbook as `ansible-playbook <playbook_name> --ask-sudo-pass`